# How do I restrict access to a broadcast message in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I understand routing (I think), but what's to stop User A from looking at User B's client-side  source to discover the socket.io URL specific to each user and then build their own script to start listening for broadcast messages on that particular channel?

Comment: How are they looking at User B's client-side source? Wouldn't that require having either physical access to that machine, or to have compromised the machine to the point where they can view web requests post SSL decryption? At that point, the user is effectively hosed and there really isn't any way for you to protect against it on the server side. Even cookies as mentioned by Jani are a minor inconvenience as User A would have access to those cookies as well. Did I misunderstand something in the question?

Comment: No, you're exactly right. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something inherent to security of socket.io's communication to make it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use something to determine who the client is. Once you do that, you could for example use the rooms feature, and only broadcast to the specific room where you put all your authorized users.

To identify the client, you could pass in cookies from the browser in a socket.io request, and compare that to any session data you have stored in Express/Connect/Whatever.

Comment: This is actually a great article about the process in general, for anyone looking for similar information: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Comment: @EvilJordan I think it would become a tad tricky. Session storage already puts a cookie to the client which is already used pretty much exactly for this purpose (to identify who the client is so we know what session data to make available)

Comment: agreed. It's looking like the traditional external user-auth and then namespaces are the way to go. Which leads me to another question I'll be opening soon!